# C# (.NET) Objects with dependent life-cycle on owning objects

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, dependency-management

I am coming from C++ background and would like to have some thoughts from C# (.NET) experts on the problem statement below, I am open to solution approaches but requirements are frozen.

**Problem Statement:**

1. To have a system that provides automatic cleaning of dependent objects as soon as the owning objects are deleted (bit different from what GC provides explained below.)
2. Dependent objects may have other references other than its owning object, but as soon as owning object is deleted the dependent objects needs to go
3. To be able to replace the other outstanding references with stub object (placeholder) references as the actual object no longer exit
4. The system needs to be object agnostic and should be able to detect references or replace them with stubs for any object inherited from System.Object (.net)

***Definition of terms:***

Dependent Object: An object that always needs an owner, but may be referenced by other objects as well. The Life cycle of dependent object will however be ***completely*** owned by owning object. If the owning object is deleted the dependent object must be deleted.

Stub objects These are the objects that represents the reference that got deleted.

**Functional Background**

To be able to support the functional requirements we need a system that will automatically clean up the dependent objects who's owner are deleted and then it would replace other  references with the stub to indicate that the object it was holding has been deleted or unloaded,

To explain this with a simple example

1. Time T1 - Lets say we create a Line object. Since creating a line needs a start and end point it created 2 Point (Pt1 and Pt2) objects. The Point objects are marked as Dependent objects and Line Object is the Owner. So at any point of time if we delete Line it should go and delete Pt1 and Pt2.
2. Time T2: We create two new points Pt3 and Pt4 (these are now independent objects)
3. Time T3: We create a Curve object which is referencing (Pt2, Pt3 and Pt4). Here the Pt2's lifecycle is controled by Line object.
4. Time T4: We delete the Line object from graphics, now as a requirement this operation must go and delete Pt1 and Pt2 as they were create by Line and Line object has been deleted.
5. Time T5: Since curve was also referencing Pt2 hence now its geometric computation is incomplete and will be made to reference to a stub object. The Curve object will be marked as broken so that in future point of time we can edit it to refer to new point.

[image]

The key issues in having this system is that because deleting is controlled by .NET system, we do not have control over it. Any thought how this can be achieved in C# or .NET (In C++ we have complete control over memory management so it possible to determine active references from a pointer before we delete it and remove or replace them in memory).

I understand the Garbage Collector has its own tremendous benefits, but this is critical requirements which we need to support in .NET based C# model as well.

Any thought, suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need this fine level of control?

Comment: *To have a system that provides automatic cleaning of dependent objects as soon as the owning objects are deleted (bit different from what GC provides explained below.)* You can't really force object deletion in C#. You can run a `GC.Collect()` and hope, but it isn't the "right" way to do it. C# doesn't have deterministic finalization/collection of objects. What you can have is the `Dispose()`, that can be used to free part of the resources used by an object (not the "base memory" of the object)

Comment: The example that i gave is very simple...  we have the architecture that is based on C++ right now, but going forward we will be supporting .NET based languages as well. We are into heavy geometric and associative based computational software and we always need to deal with situations all the time. There are dependent associations that may be deleted or not loaded at all if they are persisted in different files.

Comment: From what I understand, what you really need is a way to flag an object (and its references) as dirty. Whether it's actually deleted from memory right away or after the garbage collector runs shouldn't have any impact on your use case.

Comment: Thanks KooKiz, Yes I thought about the Dirty field approach, but as i have said this needs to be managed by system level. If an object is marked as Dirty other objects can still access data from it and also potentially change it. Imagine you are modelling a mathematical model of a car this would typically contain millions of objects and many associations with each other so in our case dependent deletion needs to be enforced by the underlying architecture and system.

Comment: One approach might be that you use "normal" references for owner --> element and weak references to reference to not owned objects (stubs) This way you cannot control the exact time when a point becomes invalid, (is that really required?), but you have the stub behavior (weak reference) implemented by the system.

Comment: You still haven't explained _why_ you need control over it.  I'm inferring that you don't trust the Garbage Collector to clear memory quickly (and you're _assuming_ that it won't meet your needs, or you are just irritated with the lack of control.  Either way, if you want complete control over memory usage you can't use a managed framework like .NET.  You may be better off keeping your library in C++ and writing a .NET API using [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI).

Comment: Before embarking on any plan to manage memory in C# read Eric Lippert's two posts on finalizers and the garbage collector. http://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/ and http://ericlippert.com/2015/05/21/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-two/ . You'll probably want to avoid the use of finalizers afterward.

Comment: Is it allowed for you to insert facades into this model? Where nobody gets a direct reference to an object (except maybe the owner), and everyone else gets access via the facade. When the object should be "deleted", it removes itself from the facade.

Comment: Thanks, The need of the control is what i have explained in the simplified example above. Unless you delete Pt2 as soon as Line object is deleted how are we going to restrict the Curve object to not use its data or even modify it. ? At this point curve object is expected to be in an invalid state as its geometry cannot be computed as Pt1 and Pt2 will be deleted as soon as line is deleted.

Comment: The only way to replace which object a reference refers to is to modify the reference. As such, when you delete the line, and hence delete the points, you need to modify the reference stored in the curve. If you can't/won't do that, you need to wrap such objects in wrappers that may or may not have content. Then the curve would refer to the same wrapper it has always referred to but you tell the wrapper to forget about the internal point. Either way, this has to be done explicitly, there's nothing in .NET that will "figure this out automatically" for you.

Comment: Since the line would also refer to the wrappers, you would basically go through the wrapped points for the line, and since it owns those points you would ask each wrapper to forget about its wrapped point. Then you would remove the line and its references to the wrappers from your object graph, which would make those objects eligible for collection. Since nobody refers to the line or the wrapper for point2 any more, those wrappers will be collected. The wrapper still referenced by the curve will be kept, but you explicitly cleared out the internal point which makes the curve invalid.

Comment: Thanks Lasse, just that I don't want this to specific to lines and curves. Need to abstract this out so that the behavior can be used by any object that needs dependency based update and deletion.

Comment: Check this [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program: https://www.dropbox.com/s/og2jq3tyktcfmb8/SO30505981.linq?dl=1

Comment: @Ameya I've read it twice now, and from what I deduce you're looking for a simple `WeakReference<T>` for the non-owners and `T` for the owners. You can wrap it in a stub if you want - or call the WeakReference itself the stub. If you want to be sure, call `GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you can't control the deallocation of memory in C#. As suggested by Ameya, what you can do is have a "dirty" flag.

> Yes I thought about the Dirty field approach, but as i have said this needs to be managed by system level. If an object is marked as Dirty other objects

Note that in .NET there are plenty of classes that do exactly this: many `IDisposable` classes (the ones that inherit from `Stream` especially!) When `Dispose()`d, theiy set a `disposed` flag to `true`, and in properties/methods they do a `if (disposed) throw ObjectDisposedException()`. In your case you shouldn't do this, you should simply `return;` or `return (some default value)`;

```
public class ObjectWithReferences : IDisposable
{
    private List<ObjectWithReferences> childs;

    protected readonly ObjectWithReferences Parent;

    public bool IsDisposed { get; private set; }

    protected ObjectWithReferences(ObjectWithReferences parent)
    {
        Parent = parent;

        if (parent != null)
        {
            parent.AddChild(this);
        }
    }

    private void AddChild(ObjectWithReferences child)
    {
        if (IsDisposed)
        {
            child.Dispose();
            return;
        }

        if (childs == null)
        {
            childs = new List<ObjectWithReferences>();
        }

        childs.Add(child);
    }

    private void DisposeChilds()
    {
        if (childs == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (ObjectWithReferences child in childs)
        {
            if (!child.IsDisposed)
            {
                child.Dispose();
            }
        }

        childs = null;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!IsDisposed)
        {
            try
            {
                Dispose(true);
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    DisposeChilds();
                }
                finally
                {
                    IsDisposed = true;
                    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ~ObjectWithReferences()
    {
        if (!IsDisposed)
        {
            try
            {
                Dispose(false);
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    DisposeChilds();
                }
                finally
                {
                    IsDisposed = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Does nothing, not necessary to call!
    }
}
```

Example of use:

```
public class ExampleRoot : ObjectWithReferences
{
    public ExampleRoot() : base(null)
    {
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        if (IsDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Do Foo things
    }

    public void CreateChild()
    {
        if (IsDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Auto-adds itself!
        var child = new ExampleChild(this);
    }
}

public class ExampleChild : ObjectWithReferences
{
    private byte[] BigBuffer = new byte[1000000];

    public ExampleChild(ExampleRoot parent) : base(parent)
    {
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // The ExampleChild object has a very long possible lifetime,
        // because it will live even in the IsDisposed == true state,
        // so it is better to free even managed resources.
        BigBuffer = null;
    }
}
```

The code is quite simple/clear... There are two example classes (a `Root` and a `Child`). The basic idea is a "special" object, `ObjectWithReferences` that keeps the references of its childs. It is `IDisposable`, and when `Dispose()` is called (or when it is finalized) it `Dispose()` all its child objects. You can inherit from this object with your classes. Everyone of your methods/properties should always check the `IsDisposed` property to see if the object has been disposed. If it has been disposed, they should do nothing and return default values (0, `null`, `string.Empty`, ...). Note that if one of this objects keeps references to big managed objects (arrays for example), contrary to suggested .NET guidelines, it should `null` these references to let the GC collect them.

Note that it is the constructor that adds the object that is being built to its parent!

Comment: Thanks xanatos... this is still error prone in the mathematical, dependency and computational based data model as it needs the referencing object to check for Dirty which a programmer needs to do manually and there is a chance that object state can be changed even if it is dirty, and hence we need system to enforce any data query or edit is disallowed on a dependent object whose owner is deleted. If the owner is present then data access, edit is allowed.

Comment: @Ameya You shouldn't have public fields, only properties. Properties can do the checking. *which a programmer needs to do manually* this part is right, but it is the responsability of every method to do it. Note that you could write a Fody plugin to do it for you. There is already something similar that adds a `throw ObjectDisposedException()`: https://github.com/Fody/Janitor

Comment: Yes agreed and we do not plan to have public fields, but with properties access is possible (even if we check in the get methods and raise exception if the object is dirty) from an architecture perceptive this is not generic enough to be used by any object. Also its just not feasible to expect each and every reference to start coping with dependent dirty object. Its way to object specific coding. More over if the dependent object is lying then dev can use reflection to do anything to its values:)...

Comment: @Ameya I do think you haven't comprehended. If the object Point is Disposed and then is used by someone, it will do nothing/return default values, because every method/property of the Point object checks if `this.IsDisposed`. Note that even in your analysis you write `The Curve object will be marked as broken so that in future point of time we can edit it to refer to new point.` but you dont write how it should be obtained. Curve has two alternatives: continue using Point without checking if it is disposed (and take default values if it is disposed), or always check if Point is disposed.

Answer (score 0):

The normal thing to do here would be to use a `WeakReference`.

If you need the stub behaviour to be automatic, you could do something like:

```
public class AutoStubbed<T> where T:class
{
  private WeakReference<T> _reference;
  private T _stub;
  private readonly Func<T> _stubFactory;
  public AutoStubbed(T value, T stub)
  {
    _reference = new WeakReference<T>(value);
    _stub = stub;
  }
  public AutoStubbed(T value, Func<T> factory)
  {
    _reference = new WeakReference<T>(value);
    _stubFactory = factory;
  }
  public T Target
  {
    get
    {
      T ret;
      if(_reference.TryGetTarget(out ret))
        return ret;
      if(_stub == null && _stubFactory != null)
        _stub = _stubFactory();
      return _stub;
    }
  }
}
```

And type `T` to a interface both your object and your stub defines, rather the type of the object.

Comment: @xanatos sorry, that was a bad idea I incompletely removed. The problem with code examples in answers not giving you a compiler error when you do something silly.